# Has Quentin Quire's family been mentioned before?

Tags: marvel, x-men

*Wolverine and the X-Men* editor Jordan D. White [asked via Twitter](http://twitter.com/#!/cracksh0t/status/136847825127485440):

> Hey, X-Fans...have we ever heard any mention of Quentin Quire's family or life pre-New X-Men?

A little background: [Quentin Quire](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quentin_Quire) (aka Kid Omega) was created by Grant Morrison and Frank Quitely during their run on [*New X-Men*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_X-Men_%282001_series%29) in 2002. He has recently appeared in the X-Men event "Schism" and is now a supporting cast member of the recently launched series *Wolverine and the X-Men*. Has his life prior to appearing in *New X-Men* been referenced before?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In his first appearance (*New X-Men* #134) he found out he was adopted.